# Endpoint is null?

Tags: c#, wcf, channelfactory

I get the following error:

> The Address property on ChannelFactory.Endpoint was null. The ChannelFactory's Endpoint must have a valid Address specified

**But I have an adress for the client endpoint, what is going on here?**

Code:

```
 ChannelFactory<CommService.ITwService> myChannelFactory 
 = new ChannelFactory<CommService.ITwService>();
 CommService.ITwService wcfClient1 = myChannelFactory.CreateChannel();
```

Client:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
  </system.web>
  <!-- When deploying the service library project, the content of the config file must be added to the host's 
  app.config file. System.Configuration does not support config files for libraries. -->
  <system.serviceModel>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/CommService/Service1/"
        binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="CommService.ITwService"
        name="Super">
        <identity>
          <dns value="localhost" />
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
    </client>
    <services />
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, 
          set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 
          set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment 
          to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>

</configuration>
```

Server:

```xml
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
  <configuration>

    <system.web>
      <compilation debug="true" />
    </system.web>
    <!-- When deploying the service library project, the content of the config file must be added to the host's 
    app.config file. System.Configuration does not support config files for libraries. -->
    <system.serviceModel>
      <client>
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/CommService/Service1/"
          binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" contract="CommService.ITwService"
          name="" kind="" endpointConfiguration="">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
            <certificateReference storeName="My" storeLocation="LocalMachine"
              x509FindType="FindBySubjectDistinguishedName" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
      </client>
      <services>
        <service name="CommService.Service1">
          <endpoint address="SuperEndPoint" binding="wsHttpBinding" name="SuperEndPoint"
            contract="CommService.ITwService">
            <identity>
              <dns value="localhost" />
            </identity>
          </endpoint>
          <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
          <host>
            <baseAddresses>
              <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/CommService/Service1/" />
            </baseAddresses>
          </host>
        </service>
      </services>
      <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
          <behavior>
            <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, 
            set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
            <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
            <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 
            set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment 
            to avoid disclosing exception information -->
            <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
          </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
      </behaviors>
    </system.serviceModel>

  </configuration>
```

Comment: Have you tried the other overloads of ChannelFactory? In which you give either EndPoint or endPointConfigurationName.

Comment: @Amar now I did. it would not read from my app.config.

Comment: Do you want to read configuration from Config file? Your statement is little confusing. Anyways looks like you have Win Form or Console app as your service client. The .config file should be there where your .exe resides, secondly the name of .config file should be same as that of .exe file. Plz let me know if I'm on right track.

Comment: You say *it did not read from my app.config* - yet the client config you posted appears to be a `web.config` (for a web site/app) .... what is your client? A web app or a console/WPF/Winforms app??

Comment: Can you browse to your service from IE and see the wsdl without any problems?

Comment: As Amur is suggesting, replace your code with this `ChannelFactory<CommService.ITwService> myChannelFactory 
 = new ChannelFactory<CommService.ITwService>("SuperEndPoint");` to get your proxy to use the config file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved this by creating a new project.. creating the files and copying the code to the new project using copy paste.. weird.